# Issue with Retrofit Response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, spinner

I am trying to get List of States through Retrofit and trying to add in Searchable Spinner.

What I get :

I am getting List of States in Response.

I can access one state in Spinner.
[image: Picture of Json]
What i want :

I want to access multiple States in Spinner.

Code :

```
getMainApp().electAPI.getStates().enqueue(object : Callback<Responseval>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Responseval>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Responseval>, response: Response<Responseval>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful!!){
                    val states = response.body()?.data
                    val stateArray = arrayListOf<String>(states?.get(0)!!.name)// Problem occur here i need to put value to get state
                    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateArray)
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    spinner.adapter = adapter
                    val options = stateArray
                    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, " You select >> "+options[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

                            // sometimes you need nothing here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })
```

Pokos :

```
data class Responseval(val `data`: List<Data>, val message: String, val success: Boolean)

data class Data(val created_at: String, val id: Int, val name: String, val status: Int, val updated_at: String)
```

Comment: You need to post the json response

Comment: added sir @SantanuSur

Comment: this just because of  arrayListOf<String>(states?.get(0)!!.name). You have just get the first name of the state.

Comment: Right i want all states in name it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop like this.

```
getMainApp().electAPI.getStates().enqueue(object : Callback<Responseval>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Responseval>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Responseval>, response: Response<Responseval>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful!!){
                    val states = response.body()?.data
                    var stateArray = arrayListOf<String>
                    for(i = 0; i<response.body.data.size; i++){
                        stateArray.add(response.body.data.get(i).name)
                    }
                    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateArray)
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    spinner.adapter = adapter
                    val options = stateArray
                    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, " You select >> "+options[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

                            // sometimes you need nothing here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })
```

for loop in kotlin

```
for (i in 0..(response.body.data.size-1)) {
        stateArray.add(response.body.data.get(i).name)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getMainApp().electAPI.getStates().enqueue(object : Callback<Responseval>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Responseval>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Responseval>, response: Response<Responseval>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful!!){
                val states = response.body()?.data
                val stateArray = Array<String>(states.size())
for(int i=0;i<sates.size();i++)
{
    stateArray[i]=sates.get(i).name;

    if(i == (sates.size() -1) )
    {
     val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateArray)
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                spinner.adapter = adapter
                val options = stateArray
                spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, " You select >> "+options[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

                        // sometimes you need nothing here
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
        }

    })
```

You are just accessing the first position on the list that's why spinner is displaying only one option.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

This method will make it short add items in array

```
getMainApp().electAPI.getStates().enqueue(object : Callback<Responseval>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Responseval>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Responseval>, response: Response<Responseval>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful!!){
                    val states = response.body()?.data
                    var stateArray = arrayListOf<String>
                    for(state in states){
                        stateArray.add(states.get(i).name)
                    }
                    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateArray)
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    spinner.adapter = adapter
                    val options = stateArray
                    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, " You select >> "+options[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

                            // sometimes you need nothing here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })
```