# How to loop a JSONOBJECT?

Tags: java, json

Iam trying to loop A JSONOBJECT from an api, but using this code only gave me the first values, since I have a cardviewlayout, everytime that the jsonobjects gets looped, I want to get different values, but using this code below gave me looping but with first values which kept being the same

I tried to iterate the jsonobject values, but for each loop, i keep the getting same info of the first part, but not looping and getting different values

```
 final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = response.getJSONObject("teams");
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("Match");
                Iterator<String>  temp = jsonObject.keys();
                while (temp.hasNext()){
                    String key = temp.next();
                    String date = jsonObject.getString( "Date" );
                    String league = jsonObject.getString("League");
                    String stadium = jsonObject.getString("Stadium");
                    int round = jsonObject.getInt("Round");
                    String hometeam = jsonObject.getString("HomeTeam");
                    ///// versus photo here//
                    String awayteam = jsonObject.getString("AwayTeam");
                    int homescore = jsonObject.getInt("HomeGoals");
                    String time = jsonObject.getString("Time");
                    int awayscore = jsonObject.getInt("AwayGoals");
                    String homedetails = jsonObject.getString("HomeGoalDetails");

                    arrayList.add(new modeclasslivescore(date, league, stadium, round, hometeam,
                            R.drawable.vsphoto, awayteam, homescore, time, awayscore, homedetails));
                }
                adapterlivescore = new adapterlivescore(arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterlivescore);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: post your json.

Comment: What's Android Studio got to do with this question?

Comment: why would you want to loop if you are getting desired object direct using get.

Comment: This is the json  {  
   "teams":{  
      "Match":{  
         "Date":"2019-04-18T09:50:00+00:00",
         "League":"Australian A-League",
         "Round":"26",
         "HomeTeam":"Sydney FC",
         "HomeTeam_Id":"134473",
         "AwayTeam":"Perth Glory",
         "AwayTeam_Id":"134481",
         "Time":"Finished",
         "HomeGoals":"1",
         "AwayGoals":"0",
         "HomeGoalDetails":"37':Adam Le Fondre;",
         "AwayGoalDetails":{

Comment: Karan Mer , with jsonarray before when i use the for loop , i get everytime different values thru jsonobject.getString(i); but since in this json , i should loop JSONOBJECT value , i could only the first values with iterator

Comment: This is json from an api of soccer , basically of soccer live score , many teams play at the time , but i only get the first two teams playing and keeps looping , i dont get other teams

Comment: Post your full JSON in a question, and format it correctly.

Comment: what are you using to make this RST call? why don;t you just use JSON parserer to get object?

Comment: Lukas Novicky, thank you for the anwser , but i never used Json parserer , can you please show me how or if there is any piece of code as an example thank you.

Comment: @takieddine please try with forloop or foreach loop its better you can check my question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55530807/10182897

Comment: and please post your json Response so user can Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting json response as single object, because your response dosen't contain array which is defined in "[]" and it has single object which is defined in "{}"

If this is your response:

```
{
  "teams": {
    "Match": [
      {
        "Date": "2019-04-18T09:50:00+00:00",
        "League": "Australian A-League",
        "Round": "26",
        "HomeTeam": "Sydney FC",
        "HomeTeam_Id": "134473",
        "AwayTeam": "Perth Glory",
        "AwayTeam_Id": "134481",
        "Time": "Finished",
        "HomeGoals": "1",
        "AwayGoals": "0",
        "HomeGoalDetails": "37':Adam Le Fondre;"
      },
{
        "Date": "2019-04-18T09:50:00+00:00",
        "League": "Australian A-League",
        "Round": "26",
        "HomeTeam": "Sydney FC",
        "HomeTeam_Id": "134473",
        "AwayTeam": "Perth Glory",
        "AwayTeam_Id": "134481",
        "Time": "Finished",
        "HomeGoals": "1",
        "AwayGoals": "0",
        "HomeGoalDetails": "37':Adam Le Fondre;"
      },
{
        "Date": "2019-04-18T09:50:00+00:00",
        "League": "Australian A-League",
        "Round": "26",
        "HomeTeam": "Sydney FC",
        "HomeTeam_Id": "134473",
        "AwayTeam": "Perth Glory",
        "AwayTeam_Id": "134481",
        "Time": "Finished",
        "HomeGoals": "1",
        "AwayGoals": "0",
        "HomeGoalDetails": "37':Adam Le Fondre;"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This should be your code:

```
/*Create Your List Object*/

    for (int i : jsonObject) { 
                 jsonObject.get(i).getString("Date");
                jsonObject.get(i).getString("league");
                jsonObject.get(i).getString("stadium");
                jsonObject.get(i).getString("round");
                jsonObject.get(i).getString("hometeam");
                jsonObject.get(i).getString("Time");
                jsonObject.get(i).getString("AwayTeam");
                jsonObject.get(i).getString("HomeGoalDetails");
    /*Add object to List*/
            }
```

Comment: Please check now and I have also mentioned exact json required for that.So It was not just copy paste.

Comment: It says that for each is not applicable for JSONOBJECT –

Answer (score 0):

You are looping it in wrong way, every time you are calling

```
String date = jsonObject.getString( "Date" );
```

you will get the first object

Comment: well i dont know how im going to look a JSONOBJECT, i did loop the JSONARRAY easily, but it is the first time i deal with JSONOBJECT getting info from api to be looped and stored in the variabales