# How to get the selected items from dynamic created spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I have a spinner that loads dynamic data from server. Each item in the spinner also has custom layout .
I managed to show the data in the spinner. Can somebody help me in getting the selected value ?

I have tried spinner.getItemIdAtPosition(position) but i'm getting the result as 0 even if i click any item.

This is my adapter code:

```
class CustomDropDownAdapter(val context: Context, var batchList: Array<BatchList>) : BaseAdapter() {


    val mInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view: View
        val vh: ItemRowHolder
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.batch_row_spinner, parent, false)
            vh = ItemRowHolder(view)
            view?.tag = vh
        } else {
            view = convertView
            vh = view.tag as ItemRowHolder
        }


        vh.date.text = batchList.get(position).expiry_date
        vh.availQty.text = "Available: ${batchList.get(position).available_quantity}"
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {

        return null

    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {

        return 0

    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return batchList.size
    }

    private class ItemRowHolder(row: View?) {

        val date: TextView
        val availQty: TextView

        init {
            this.date = row?.findViewById(R.id.date) as TextView
            this.availQty = row?.findViewById(R.id.available) as TextView
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Function where i load in spinner

```
/**Method to load all items in spinner */
private fun loadBatch(medicineId:String,pharmaId:String)
{
    val call=RetrofitClient.instance.api.displayBatchList("Bearer $token",20.toString(),medicineId,0.toString(),pharmaId)
    call.enqueue(object :Callback<Array<BatchList>>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Array<BatchList>>, response: Response<Array<BatchList>>) {
           if(response.code()==200)
           {

                   var spinnerAdapter: CustomDropDownAdapter = CustomDropDownAdapter(context!!, response.body()!!)
               updateMedView.pharmaSpinerbatch.adapter = spinnerAdapter


           }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Array<BatchList>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Batch Load error",t.message)
        }


    })


}
```

I need to get the selected item

Comment: you have two options , 1. setOnItemClickListener and get the position of the selected item
if you are using spinner then you should have 2. SelectListener and get position of the selected since spinner gets only one thing to be selected
do you have either ?

Comment: What after getting the position of the selected item?? Then what to check??

Comment: if you get the position of the selected item then you can get the item itself as since you sent your **batchList** to the adapter so you have instance of it.
So everytime it's being selected you can use batchList.get(position) 
since you have the position itself and you now have the item (Object) that has been selected.

Comment: don't send directly response to the spinner better put that response in array so it will be filtered then you can follow some steps if you want to i'll post it

Comment: yes please post @Ashish

Comment: @RT16 can you edit you're code and put you're data in variable like my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530327/issue-with-retrofit-response). it's same for you're spinner if it works with you. Upvote the question.

Comment: Thanks I.m able to get the items data.

Comment: @RT16 is there anything i can help with ?

Answer (score 0):

Add listner for your spiner

```
//item selected listener for spinner
mySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

                override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, myStrings[p2], LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }
```

Comment: sometime better show them proper answer in comments might it will help them.